# populate enum fields with application.properties and java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

with spring xml configuration, it is possible to define the following in app context xml to populate the status field in the `TestEnum`:

app context xml

```
    <bean id="blue" class="com.example.demo.test.TestEnum" factory-method="valueOf">
        <property name="status" value="${testnum.blue.status}"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>BLUE</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="red" class="com.example.demo.test.TestEnum" factory-method="valueOf">
        <property name="status" value="${testnum.red.status}"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>RED</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

enum class

```
public enum TestEnum {
    
    BLUE,
    RED;
    
    private String status;
    
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

mystatus.properties

```
testnum.blue.status=good
testnum.red.status=bad
```

Is this possible with spring boot using application.properties + java configuration without xml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a simple environment configuration class (annotated with [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) for example), will map and do the conversion of your enum automatically.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.property.path")
public class TestConfiguration{

    public enum TestEnum {
        BLUE, RED
    }

    @NotNull
    private TestEnum type;

    public TestConfiguration() {
    }

    public @NotNull TestEnum getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(@NotNull TestEnum type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you show how to define `my.property.path` with `red` and `blue` in application.properties also?

Comment: Can the `blue` and `red` be a field in the TestEnum instead of a separate class?

Comment: In the question, `private String color;` is part of the enum, not an outer `TestConfiguration` class

Comment: My example is not very good, I will change the `color` field to something else to make more clear

Comment: Ok, sorry I this case the property path, is "my.property.path.type=RED"